For the Frobenius automorphism, must the fixed field be prime order?
Does it make sense to discuss the Frobenius automorphism when the fixed field has prime power order? For example GF(16)/GF(4) or GF(81)/GF(9)? I can't see anything immediately wrong, but I've never seen somebody do so.
Both examples I've given have Galois groups $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

For any prime power $q$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the Frobenius automorphism $x\to x^q$ is a generator of the Galois group of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}/\mathbb{F_q}$. There is no difference between prime and prime power here.

@Mark can I have you restate this as an answer so I can close this question?

Ok, I added an answer.

For any prime power $q$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the Frobenius automorphism $x\to x^q$ is a generator of the Galois group of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}/\mathbb{F_q}$. (which is a Galois extension) There is no difference between prime and prime power here.
